# Unable to pass quoted strings to the python script within a docker container

Tags: python, docker, escaping, double-quotes

Unable to pass quoted strings to the python script within a docker container. The quoted string is split as two independent items of the sys.argv vector.

The expected behaviour of the python script is as follows.

```
check.py --coverage 'Hello World' --blabla something
All Raw Arguments
['--coverage', 'Hello World', '--blabla', 'something']
All Args
Namespace(blabla='something', coverage='Hello World')

Print Coverage
Hello World

Print blabla
something
```

The same script when I have it within the docker container and run using `docker run`, the text inside quotes is split into multiple vars of the list.

```
docker run --rm -i sample --coverage 'Hello World' --blabla something
All Raw Arguments
['--coverage', 'Hello', 'World', '--blabla', 'sometext']
usage: check.py [-h] [--coverage COVERAGE] [--blabla BLABLA]
check.py: error: unrecognized arguments: World
```

**Note** The difference in the sys.argv vector when the script is run normally and from within the docker

```
['--coverage', 'Hello World', '--blabla', 'something']
['--coverage', 'Hello', 'World', '--blabla', 'sometext']
```

*In the first instance it is only one item 'Hello World', whereas when the script is inside docker it is 'Hello', 'World'*

My sample dockerfile definition is as follows

```
FROM sample_base

ENTRYPOINT ["/check.py"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

Breaking my head for the past couple of hours. Any help is much appreciated

Tried all different combinations such as follows.

```
docker run --rm -i sample '--coverage "Hello\\\ World" --blabla sometext'
docker run --rm -i sample --coverage "Hello\\\ World" --blabla sometext
docker run --rm -i sample --coverage "Hello\ World" --blabla sometext
docker run --rm -i sample --coverage \"Hello World\" --blabla sometext
docker run --rm -i sample --coverage \"\"Hello World\"\" --blabla sometext
docker run --rm -i sample --coverage "\"\"Hello World\"\"" --blabla sometext
export COVERAGE="Hello World"
docker run --rm -i sample --coverage $COVERAGE --blabla sometext
docker run --rm -i sample --coverage ${COVERAGE} --blabla sometext
docker run --rm -i sample --coverage "$COVERAGE" --blabla sometext
docker run --rm -i sample --coverage "${COVERAGE}" --blabla sometext
```

**Note** All the above combination were tried with single quotes (') as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`docker run --rm -i sample sh -c '/check.py --coverage $COVERAGE --blabla sometext'`

or `bash`

Comment: and if $COVERAGE is an actual SQL statement with parameter='value' ? :/

Answer (score 0):

Did you also tried `docker run --rm -i sample --coverage "\"Hello World\"" --blabla sometext`?

I've had some problems with spaces using docker too and had to escape the quotes even though the code interpreter marked it as an error.

Comment: Tried this as well. The 6th one in the above sample is similar to this. For double checking, tried the exact one and still failed.

Comment: Can you tell me what's your docker version? because I was testing with the v17.12.0-ce and tried to simulate your case with a python script as the container's entry point and executed it this way:

`docker run -it gomod/alpine --opt "no hello world"`

And it received the full text `no hello world` as the third command line parameter. @ArunThundyillSaseendran

Comment: Check out [https://labs.play-with-docker.com/](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/) and try your implementation with this version